# output xml array parsing php repeated six times

Tags: php, loops

I have a php file in this format:

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password= "";
$db = "kamus1";
mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password) or die("koneksi ke MySQL gagal");
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("koneksi ke dataBase gagal");

$doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
$root = $doc->createElement('movies');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
$arr = array();

//$query=mysql_query("select id,istilah,definisi from kamus_jaringan");
$query=mysql_query("select * from kamus_jaringan");
while($get_data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
foreach($get_data as $fieldname=>$fieldvalue)
{

$item = $doc->createElement('movie');
$item = $root->appendChild($item);
$item ->setAttribute("id",$get_data["id"]);
$item ->setAttribute("istilah",$get_data["istilah"]);
$item ->setAttribute("definisi",$get_data["definisi"]);
}
}
echo $doc->saveXML();
$doc->save("movies.xml");
?>
```

when this code is executed on the browser, the output of each of the data will be repeated up to six times. for example id, will repeat six times. I want the output to each of the data, only one time. please help

Comment: Well, maybe there are up to six rows in your database? You'd have to tell us more about what you are trying to do, and what the database table looks like

Comment: Indentation is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated. Second, you have two loops and you only need one, change your code to this:

```
while($get_data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $item = $doc->createElement('movie');
    $item = $root->appendChild($item);
    $item ->setAttribute("id",$get_data["id"]);
    $item ->setAttribute("istilah",$get_data["istilah"]);
    $item ->setAttribute("definisi",$get_data["definisi"]);
}
```

Comment: :thank you very much. it works for me. thank's.... ^_^